# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Tags: sql

I really cant figure out what i did wrong. I´m passing values to the database. It works, as the values are stored. They are checkboxes from previous page, only with a value of 1, or automatic 0 in phpMyadmin.

This is my code:

```
/* SQL COMMANDS */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "****" , "buffetkeuze");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; } echo 'Connected... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli) . "\n";  

$insert = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `buffetkeuze` ( `Gourmand` , `Party` , `Polder` ,       `Frites` , `Gebakken_aardappels` , `Rijst` , `Gegratineerde_aardappels` , `Pasta` , `Ardennerham` , `Kipsate` , `Varkenssate` , `Spareribs` , `KipPiriPiri` , `Gehaktballetjes` , `Beenham` , `Minischnitzels` , `Gerooktezalm` , `Haringplateau` , `Zalmfilet` , `Kibbeling` , `Quiche` ,  `Tempuragroenten` , `Rundercarpaccio` , `Wildpate` , `Ossenhaaspuntjes` , `Ribeye` , `Blacktiger` , `ganzenborst` , `Wildragout`  , `Fazantenfilet`  , `kaasplateau`  , `geitenkaas` , `paling` , `wildezalm` , `Oesters` , `Kreeft` , `Tonijn` , `Zeetongfilet` , `Reebiefstuk` , `Hertencarpaccio` , `gerookteeendenborst` , `garnalensalade` ) 
VALUES (  '$_POST[Gourmand]','$_POST[Party]','$_POST[Polder]','$_POST[Frites]','$_POST[Gebakken_aardappels]','$   _POST[Rijst]' ,'$_POST[Gegratineerde_aardappels]','$_POST[Pasta]','$_POST[Ardennerham]','$_POST[Kipsate]','$_POST[Varkenssate]','$_POST[Spareribs]','$_POST[KipPiriPiri]','$_POST[Gehaktballetjes]','$_POST[Beenham]','$_POST[Minischnitzels]','$_POST[garnalensalade]','$_POST[Gerooktezalm]','$_POST[Haringplateau]','$_POST[Zalmfilet]','$_POST[Kibbeling]','$_POST[Quiche]','$_POST[Tempuragroenten]','$_POST[Rundercarpaccio]','$_POST[Wildpate]','$_POST[Ossenhaaspuntjes]','$_POST[Ribeye]','$_POST[Blacktiger]','$_POST[ganzenborst]','$_POST[Wildragout]','$_POST[Fazantenfilet]','$_POST[kaasplateau]','$_POST[geitenkaas]','$_POST[paling]','$_POST[wildezalm]','$_POST[Oesters]','$_POST[Kreeft]','$_POST[Tonijn]','$_POST[Zeetongfilet]','$_POST[Reebiefstuk]','$_POST[Hertencarpaccio]','$_POST[gerookteeendenborst]' ) " );

if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $insert)) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli)); } echo "values inserted " . "\n"; 

$sql =  mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM `buffetkeuze` ") ;

if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli)); } echo "values selected " . "\n"; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli,$sql)) {
$Gourmand = $row['Gourmand'];
$Party = $row['Party'];
$Polder = $row['Polder'];
$Frites = $row['Frites'];
$Gebakkenaardappels = $row['Gebakken_aardappels'];
$Rijst = $row['Rijst'];
$Gegratineerdeaardappels = $row['Gegratineerde_aardappels'];
$Pasta = $row['Pasta'];

etc.
```

What is my mistake in this one?

Comment: The SQL error message suggests something is wrong with your SQL string.  Write out the `$insert` variable and verify it.

Comment: You have some spurious whitespace here `'$   _POST[Rijst]'`, and your references to `$_POST` should have the indexes quoted. Echo the query before you execute it and look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Try your query with double-quoting the post variables and single-quoting their indexes as follows:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `buffetkeuze` (`Gourmand`, `Party`, ...) 
VALUES ('$_POST["Gourmand"]', '$_POST["Party"]', ...)" );
```

Comment: Now i get the following errors: Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\prijzen.php on line 44
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
Notice: Undefined index: Gourmand in C:\xampp\htdocs\stap2.ph' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

you need to add quotes to your post variable like this:

```
$_POST['Gourmand'],...
```

//use this in your sql like this:

```
$insert = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `buffetkeuze` ( `Gourmand` , `Party` , `Polder` ,       `Frites` , `Gebakken_aardappels` , `Rijst` , `Gegratineerde_aardappels` , `Pasta` , `Ardennerham` , `Kipsate` , `Varkenssate` , `Spareribs` , `KipPiriPiri` , `Gehaktballetjes` , `Beenham` , `Minischnitzels` , `Gerooktezalm` , `Haringplateau` , `Zalmfilet` , `Kibbeling` , `Quiche` ,  `Tempuragroenten` , `Rundercarpaccio` , `Wildpate` , `Ossenhaaspuntjes` , `Ribeye` , `Blacktiger` , `ganzenborst` , `Wildragout`  , `Fazantenfilet`  , `kaasplateau`  , `geitenkaas` , `paling` , `wildezalm` , `Oesters` , `Kreeft` , `Tonijn` , `Zeetongfilet` , `Reebiefstuk` , `Hertencarpaccio` , `gerookteeendenborst` , `garnalensalade` )
        VALUES (  "$_POST['Gourmand']","$_POST['Party']",..... ) " );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for you queries. There are lots of reasons for that, including errors like yours prevention. You current code is not correct and is vulnerable.
2. You write something like `$   _POST[Rijst]` in your values part, that is not correct variable call.
3. I guess there are more bad things in your query. Try to output the final query string and see how it looks like.